# Ubuntu Touch ota-13 update faillure?

Tags: boot, updates, ubuntu-touch

I have an BQ Aquaris E5 Ubuntu Edition and today the Ubuntu Touch ota-13 update released. So i installed the update. After the update is installed, the device booted normaly. But suddenly the screen brightness took down to the lowest level. Normaly Ubuntu turns of the screen in 1 minute idletime. That's normal but when it turns the screen of, it cannot be turned on. The only thing that turns the screen on for a couple of moments is the charger. But the screen is black. The screen turned on, but all what i see is a black screen. Can someone help me. This happened 1 time earlier to me when updating the device to 15.04 ota-9.1 (first update) But then i could reset the device easy when booting up. And now it does nothing but showing a glowing black screen when connected and released from the charger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't panic yet. So many users are facing [this issue](http://pad.lv/1623853) after OTA-13. Just wait patiently. Looks like it's taking longer than normal to apply the update. The device should boot all by itself after a few minutes (~15) of black screen. Do not press the power button. If nothing happens after say half an hour, then try long pressing the power button to turn it on.

Comment: ok. thanks for the tip for the next OTA update.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I pressed for a long time the three butons to force a reboot: I had a purple screen written "fastboot mode" and then I mannually forced reboot again and everything went back to normal after updating...